# UISearchBar displaying a label when a search produces no results, but not hiding the label again when the x in the UISearchBar is clicked

Tags: ios, uilabel, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a small situation that I can't seem to overcome.

I have a UITableView which has a UISearchBar embedded at the top. The TableView is populated by NSFetchedResultsController and CoreData.

The very first time the app is launched, with no data present, if the user tries to search, I've enabled the use of a label that comes up saying "no results found" in the middle of the screen. However, if the user clicks the x in the UISearchBar, it clears the search but doesn't again hide the label.

I don't have a cancel button for the UISearchBar (it's just the x) and I implement the use of hiding a navigation bar button when a search is active.

With this in mind, I've narrowed down the issue to the textDidChange method, but I can't seem to hide the label when the user presses x with and without the keyboard up.

I was hoping someone could potentially shed some light onto this!

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    self.eventSearchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
    if ([self.eventSearchBar.text length] > 0)
    {
        self.addButton.enabled = NO;       
    }

    // This code seems to have no effect at all
    if ([searchText length] == 0)
    {
        self.noResultsLabel.hidden = YES;
    }
    _fetchedResultsController = nil;
    NSError *error;

    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
    {

    }
    else
    {
        [self.eventTableView reloadData];
        [self.noResultsLabel setHidden:_fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count > 0];
        if (![self.eventSearchBar isFirstResponder])
        {
            self.shouldBeginEditing = NO;
            [self.eventTableView reloadData];
            [self.eventSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }
}
```

Update: Two images

[image]

[image]

Any guidance would really be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you try to use `UISearchDisplayController`

Comment: Thanks Himanshu - I'm too far into my app to change now and I just have this small issue before I'm ready to update my app to the App Store.. so I may consider it for the future, but for now, this small issue needs my attention with this approach and I feel I'm missing one or two lines at the most

Comment: You want to clear the textfield of search bar on the action of button?

Comment: The UISearchBar x is already clearing the search. What I want to happen is, when you press the x, for the label to also hide itself.

Comment: have u used any action for X button ?

Comment: Can you please provide a screen shot?

Comment: Thanks @VMC501 - not that I can see.. or rather I'm not sure where I'd do this. I've seen some code online that states it's possible to "resign the first responder"with the x button clicked by appending code in the textDidChange, but I did that and although the keyboard resigns, the label isn't hiding. I'm wondering if it's a refresh, or a reloadData required.

Comment: do one thing. create a button over X and write a function which hides a labes and other things which u want to do with that particular button

Comment: Updated question with images. 
Thanks @vmc501 - I will attempt that, but the x is doing everything I want it to now, just not hiding the label. It clears the SearchBar, it dismisses the keyboard, but it doesn't hide the label

Comment: do you want to remove *search all entries*

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi - I want to remove the label that says "No Results Found."

Comment: then you can simply call `[label removeFromSuperView];`

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get this working as I desire.

I figured out that the following code in my textDidChange acts when the keyboard is still up and the user presses the x button:

```
    if (![self.eventSearchBar isFirstResponder])
    {
        self.shouldBeginEditing = NO;
        [self.eventTableView reloadData];
        [self.eventSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

So within here, I put the self.noResultsLabel.hidden = YES;

With wanting to also hide the noResultsLabel if the keyboard is the first responder and the user presses the x, I did the following:

```
    if ([self.eventSearchBar isFirstResponder] && ([self.eventSearchBar.text length] == 0))
    {
        self.noResultsLabel.hidden = YES;
        self.addButton.enabled = YES;

        [self.eventTableView reloadData];
    }
```

Now, the user can press the x button in the UISearchBar and it will hide the noResultsLabel if it's showing if the keyboard is or is not the firstResponder.

Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You just check the condition whether the search text length is 0 or not and if length is 0 then hide that label.

/** called when text changes (including clear) */

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText1
  {

  if ([searchText1 length] == 0) {

  ```
     //Hide The label
  ```

  }

}

Comment: Thanks @VMC501 and vipul for your help. Absolutely, I've got it working with my answer to the question. I'll accept in 2 days when I can. Thanks for your time with this.

Comment: pls post your working answer below so that it might be helpful to others